# Button covered by another button, thus can't be tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a `smallButton` and a `giantButton` on screen, `giantButton` is not enabled at start, when `smallButton` is tapped, it goes to hide and `giantButton` appears.

My problem is, it seems like `smallButton` is covered by `giantButton`, when I tap `smallButton`, its IBAction won't be triggered, it's linked well in storyboard.

Is it because `smallButton` is covered by `giantButton`, or something else?

Comment: Have you placed them above each other?

Comment: @RashwanL yes, I can't say which one is exactly on top tho

Comment: You can hide the giant button when viewLoads and unhide when small button pressed vice versa

Comment: Problem solved, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

If you set any instance of a UIView to hidden (or alpha 0) it will not block UI interaction.

See if disabling `userInteractionEnabled` helps you or you could `override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool` in your subclass and pass touch events through...

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem, this `giantButton` is contained inside a stack view, though I tried hide/disable `giantButton`, this stack view is still blocking my interaction.

I disabled user interaction of the stack view according to @der_michael's suggestion, now it works.

Comment: You didn't mention a stack view in your question 

Comment: @der_michael ☺️ didn't even realize it was there